# Calling a REST service with Python

Tags: python, web-services, rest, post

I have a REST service that I'm trying to call. It requires something similar to the following syntax:

```
http://someServerName:8080/projectName/service/serviceName/
      param1Name/param1/param2Name/param2
```

I have to connect to it using POST. I've tried reading up on it online ([here](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-rest.html) and [here](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/webservices/tutorials/06_programming/python/rest/urllib#http_post), for example)... but this is my problem:

If I try using the HTTP get request method, by building my own path, like this:

```
BASE_PATH = "http://someServerName:8080/projectName/service/serviceName/"
urllib.urlopen(BASE_PATH + "param1/" + param1 + "/param2/" + param2)
```

it gives me an error saying that GET is not allowed.

If I try using the HTTP post request method, like this:

```
params = { "param1" : param1, "param2" : param2 }
urllib.urlopen(BASE_PATH, urllib.urlencode(params))
```

it returns a 404 error along with the message `The requested resource () is not available.` And when I debug this, it seems to be building the params into a query string ("param1=whatever&param2=whatever"...)

How can I use POST but pass the parameters delimited by slashes as it's expected? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is sort of unfair, but this is what ended up happening... The programmer in charge of the REST service changed it to use the `&key=value` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `urllib2`
2. You're going to have to be clever; something like

   `params = { "param1" : param1, "param2" : param2 }`

   `urllib2.urlopen(BASE_PATH + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params), " ")`

   Might work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
param1, param2 = urllib.quote_plus(param1), urllib.quote_plus(param2)
BASE_PATH = "http://someServerName:8080/projectName/service/serviceName/"
urllib.urlopen(BASE_PATH + "param1/" + param1 + "/param2/" + param2, " ")
```

The second argument to `urlopen` tells it to do a POST request, with empty data. The `quote_plus` allows you to escape special characters without being forced into the `&key=value` scheme.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... :( I'm getting the same "requested resource is not available" error as before

Comment: are you sure you are able to access the resource? do you need to authenticate yourself first? are you able to give us the url so we can test?